# Vue.js/JavaScript - Is it possible to insert a link/anchor inside a text?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a paragraph with some text that I get from some database:

```
<p> 
    {{ text }}
</p>
```

However, this text may contain some references to other pages in my aplication:

```
Sample text [reference] sample text
```

So I would like these references to get turned into links to said pages:

```
<p>
    Sample text <a href="/path/to/reference"> reference </a> sample text
</p>
```

I tried using the replace function in the script like this:

```
text.replace(/\[(.+)\]/,"<a href='/path/to/$1'>$1</a>");
```

But the characters all get escaped resulting in the anchor html code getting shown on the page.

Is there a way to stop the characters from being escaped, or even another way to turn [references] in the middle of the text into working links to another page?

Comment: Would the answer on the following question help you? [How to make links clickable in a chat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48485450/1542723), this is a question I answered a while ago that has similar requirements for links, and you probably can analyze and reuse the code for your purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want your HTML to be escaped, use the [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directive.

From the docs:

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In
> order to output real HTML, you will need to use the `v-html` directive:

Example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      text: "See defect <a href='#'>#12345</a> for details"
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{text}}</p>
  <p v-html="text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to open in new tab ?

Comment: @SS Sure, it accepts any of the same markup as a regular anchor.  As long as your user has has allowed popups or whatever, you just have to set the `target` of the anchor, see [MDN Anchor#target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target).