# Vue html render puts in additional double quote

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have the following html markup which has to be javascript string encoded because I am inserting it into an object, sending it to vue which then needs to render the html:

```
\u003ca href=\&quot;http://www.cnn.com\&quot; \u003eClick Here\u003c/a\u003e
```

However, when I then want to render this markup in a div:

```
v-html="blah"
```

I get double quotes put around each existing double quote:

```
<a href=""http://www.cnn.com"" />Click Here</a>
```

Which of course makes the browser go crazy and not render the link correctly. Any idea how I can get around this?

Comment: here an answer for your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48793437/vue-js-javascript-is-it-possible-to-insert-a-link-anchor-inside-a-text

Comment: Try applying html encoding first and then string encoding. The order you do it now causes the slash in front of `&quot;`, what causes problems if you then "string" decode it, and then "html decode it" when you put it in v-html