# Adding html in Vue.js using data filters?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, vue.js

I am trying to use the Filter feature in Vue.js to add html tags inside a String, the documents suggests this should be somehow feasible but I'm getting nowhere.  The point is the data should just a String that's brought into the html and before it's mounted the filter should search the data for key words (e.g. 'See REFERENCE') and the REFERENCE word should be turned into an anchor link.

E.g.

```
 <p>{{String | filterFunction}}</p>
```

Instead of piping out say:

```
 <p>The text string with a link</p>
```

It should pipe out the string but with a node insert.

```
 <p>The text string with a <a href="someLink">link</a></p>
```

The Vue documentation suggests javascript component assemblage is possible but so far the testing has gone poorly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make links clickable in a chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483725/how-to-make-links-clickable-in-a-chat), while this doesn't use a filter, it shows how to make links clickable in the way you seem to want it

Comment: share live demo of your code ?

Comment: Does the String in `{{ String | filterFunction }}` consist of an object or just a string?

Comment: Why not use the v-html directive? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: I was hoping for a filter method for this but I guess that's not appropriate compared to the render in a functional Vue component- thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Filters only replace as text. Since you are trying to transform plain text in HTML, you'll have to resort to `v-html` or equivalent. Check your options in the demo below.

```js
function _linkify(text) {
  return text.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
}

Vue.filter('linkify', function (value) {
    return _linkify(value)
})

Vue.component('linkify', {
  props: ['msg'],
  template: '<span v-html="linkifiedMsg"></span>',
  computed: {
   linkifiedMsg() { return _linkify(this.msg); }
  }
});

Vue.component('linkify-slot', {
  render: function (h) {
    let html = _linkify(this.$slots.default[0].text);
    return h('span',{domProps:{"innerHTML": html}})
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'The text string with a http://example.com'
  },
  methods: {
    linkifyMethod(text) {
      return _linkify(text); // simply delegating to the global function
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Doesn't work: {{ message | linkify }}</p>
  
  <p v-html="$options.filters.linkify(message)"></p>
  
  <p :inner-html.prop="message | linkify"></p>
  
  <p v-html="linkifyMethod(message)"></p>
  
  <p><linkify :msg="message"></linkify></p>
  
  <p><linkify-slot>{{ message }}</linkify-slot></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The third option met my needs `<p :inner-html.prop="message | linkify"></p>`. Thank you!

Comment: same here - the third options works as-is with no effort - thanks ;)